# Open help for VS Code on Mac OS

Tags: visual-studio-code

When typing `Command`+`Shift`+`/` in VS Code on Mac OS X, the help menu should open as it does for all other OS X applications. It doesn't seem to do anything for me; I have tried disabling extensions.

Comment: What version are you using?  On mine (1.31.1 on macOS 10.14.3) Command + Shift + / opens the help menu item with focus on the search for help option.  The same thing happens in Firefox, Apple Mail and a few other applications I just tried

Comment: Is Command+Shift+/ bound to some command within vscode?  Go to 
Gear icon/"Keyboard Shortcuts" and click the little keyboard to the right and type Command+Shift+/ and see if any command comes up.

Comment: Thanks for the responses both

@Jason I'm running 1.31.1 on OS X 10.13.6; weird that it works for you but not me. Works on all other applications, just not VS Code. A colleague replicated it.

Comment: @Mark thanks for the tip but no dice, it's not bound to anything else

Comment: This is an electron related problem, based on https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/68604